# OpenSUSE disabled root login (no root psswd set) >> yast, config issues

Tags: sudo, opensuse, root, non-root-user

I disabled the root login on my system (blank password). Now I cannot configure my system from GUI (it asks for the root password).

Everything is fine in CLI (e.g. launch yast2 from CLI works perfectly, "sudo shutdown now" etc are all good).

I need to explain to the GUI that I'm the admin and for it to stop asking me for the root password. I've got my own password as per sudoers. It should be all set with my password.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research I believe I know the answer - this is impossible to achieve. Sudo is a command line only and cannot be invoked from GUI. This answer does not explain the nature of what's happening because honestly I don't understand the details, but I made peace with the fact that it's not achievable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add yourself to the `wheel` group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G wheel $LOGNAME
```

Then GUI would ask for your password, not the root's one.

Comment: nope, didn't work, even after I logged out/in; groups now show that I'm in wheels group